# Property not found in interface that has only type of key-value in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Look at this interface:

```
interface IParams {
    [string]: number|string|Date
};
```

I'm using this interface to validate the object passing through arguments, like this:

```
someObject.do = function(params: IParams|void): void { ... }
```

It works fine, but problem is accessing param's property:

```
someObject.do = function(params: IParams|void): void {
    // property `name` (Property not found in IParams)
    const name = params.name;
    ...
}
```

I want to using IParams without any detail information, just want to validate it's type of key-value.

How do I solve this? Any suggestion will be very appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `IParams` as a generic dictionary-like object, do you'll need to make it clear to Flow that you expect to use it like a dictionary, and do

```
const name = params['name'];
```

Comment: Ok, then is there a no way to access without [] accessor? What if I want to use [] accessor, but also restrict object values with specified data types?

Comment: You can add `name: string,` to the object if you have specific keys that you care about.

Comment: What if the name is undecided?

Comment: If you don't know the name to explicitly declare it, then it has to be declared as part of the general `[string]:` key you've given, and it has to be accessed as a computed key. Since you've declared the type as `number|string|Date` it is up to you to check at runtime which of the types the property is.